# How do I find specific characters in a given string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import math

x = raw_input("Enter your address")

print ("The first number to the power of the second number in your address is", math.pow(
```

Second full week of classes just ended and I'm having troubles figuring out how to find specific things within a string.
If the user enters the address "1234 Address"
what do I need to place inside math.pow so it knows the how to find the numbers 1 and 2?

The only thing that was show in class was str.index('') which I can only use to find the location of specific characters within a string.

I have an assignment due soon that relies heavily on this so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: To clearify, how would I get python to find the first and second numbers in the address whereever they are in the address?

Comment: You mean to find 1 and 2 where ever they lie or just the first and second character of the string?

Comment: I just reread what I wrote, sorry for the confusion :(

How to find the first and second number in the string where ever they lie.

If the address were to be "Address 2542" 2 and 5 is what it should find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `x.isdigit()` to find the numbers and insert them in a list. Then use `math.pow` to find the power of the first two.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

address = raw_input("Enter your address : ")
digits = []

for c in address:
    if c.isdigit():
        digits.append(c)

if len(digits) >= 2:
    print "The first number to the power of the second number in your address is : "
    print math.pow(float(digits[0]), float(digits[1]))
else:
    print "Your address contains less than 2 numbers"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+',x)
numbers[0][0:2]
```

You need to import the regular expression. It will be more useful since you do not know the order in which the numbers will occur in the string. After which, you need to find the all the numbers in the string. '\d+' will help to get all the numbers in the string. Then all you need to do is to take the first element and take the first two numbers from that string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As strings are iteration type data in Python you can use indexing for access to a string characters ! like `my_string[1]` this give you the second character ! and then with `isdigit()` function you can check that it is digit or not !

Demo :

```
>>> s='12erge'
>>> s[1]
'2'
>>> s[1].isdigit()
True
>>> s[4]
'g'
>>> s[4].isdigit()
False
```

and for find number inside a string you can use `[regex][1]` and `re.search()` function :

```
>>> import re
>>> s='my addres is thiss : whith this number 11243783'
>>> m=re.search(r'\d+',s)
>>> print m.group(0)
11243783
```

in this code `r'\d+'` is a regular Expression that match all digits with len more than 0 ,